# Create a static table in a tabular model

Tags: ssas-tabular

I have a static dimension to create in SSAS tabular model and without creating it in the datawarehouse which is populating the cube, the dimension is like below :

```
Status                StatusID
In                    1
Out                   2
In (Exit Confirmed)   3
```

How can achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `SELECTCOLUMNS()` function in DAX to achieve this :

```
=SELECTCOLUMNS(
             {("In", 1)
             , ("Out", 2)
             , ("In (Exit Confirmed)", 3)}
             
             
             , "Status", [Value1]
             , "StatusID", [Value2]
             )
```